# How do I get strings which starts with number as start of line and ends with 5 digit number

Tags: python, regex

I have text like:

```
asf aSD  ikugfr jddc ghddfj gjn dfxg 
sdgal fghfh 16 rgjodrisgj frth fghsdf,
dfghdf dfhgdh gho h ghdof 67676

szdgfads
2 adf dojosd hsh fghs, 
zfgdf dhgdzsfb dfgdz,
dzgdzfvg 47564

asdgasdg asdg
4334 ersga errr ertgerfd ertera erers qereadf erfesfdc wefadfe, 
sfsdgfg-43647
```

I need to extract all string in which start of the line is number and ends with 5 digits. There can be multiple lines in between.

```
2 adf dojosd hsh fghs, 
zfgdf dhgdzsfb dfgdz,
dzgdzfvg 47564

4334 ersga errr ertgerfd ertera erers qereadf erfesfdc wefadfe, 
sfsdgfg-43647
```

I have tried with this regex but failed to do so. Its taking exactly two line, not single lines or more than two lines together.

```
regex = ^[0-9](.*)(?<=,)*\n?(.*\D\d{5}\D)
```

Comment: What is the regex flavor (programming language, tool, etc.)?

Comment: I don't see any line ending with 5.  Are you sure this is a job for regex?

Comment: ending with 5 digits and the programming language is Python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `^[0-9](.*)(?<=,)*\n?(.*\D\d{5}\D)` regex matches the start of a string/line, then 1 digit, then 0+ any characters (except newlines if DOTALL mode is not used), then `(?<=,)*` is supposed to check 0+ times if the preceding character is a comma (which does not make much sense though Python does not mind it), then `\n?` matches 1 or 0 newlines, `.*` matches 0+ any chars except newline, `\D` matches a non-digit, `\d{5}` matches 5 digits, and `\D` again matches a non-digit. Yucky. I do not think it can work for any matches that contain more than 3 lines (note that `\D` matches a newline), and it will never match a valid match at the end of the string as the last `\D` requires a character after the last 5 digits.

You may use

```
re.compile(r'^\d.*?\b\d{5}$', re.M|re.DOTALL)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oS7iW3/3)

You need to use a DOTALL modifier with the pattern so that `.` could match a newline, and MULTILINE modifier for the `^` and `$` to match start/end of the *line*. The `\b` will not allow matching strings with more than 5 digits at the end of the line.

Use with `re.findall`, see [demo](https://ideone.com/GBmBWb):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'^\d.*?\b\d{5}$', re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
test_str = "asf aSD  ikugfr jddc ghddfj gjn dfxg \nsdgal fghfh 16 rgjodrisgj frth fghsdf,\ndfghdf dfhgdh gho h ghdof 67676\n\nszdgfads\n2 adf dojosd hsh fghs, \nzfgdf dhgdzsfb dfgdz,\ndzgdzfvg 47564\n\nasdgasdg asdg\n4334 ersga errr ertgerfd ertera erers qereadf erfesfdc wefadfe, \nsfsdgfg-43647"
print(p.findall(test_str))
# => ['2 adf dojosd hsh fghs, \nzfgdf dhgdzsfb dfgdz,\ndzgdzfvg 47564', '4334 ersga errr ertgerfd ertera erers qereadf erfesfdc wefadfe, \nsfsdgfg-43647']
```

Comment: Its taking lines which ends with more then 5 digit numbers too.
For example: 
2 adf dojosd hsh fghs, 
zfgdf dhgdzsfb dfgdz,
dzgdzfvg 47564464566566755

Comment: Use `r'^\d.*?\b\d{5}$'`